# How can I set values for a Wordpress Post's Plugin fields via REST-API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am posting to Wordpress using the REST-API, and I need to set a variety of 'fields' for a post that are included from various plugins. As an simple example, I have an AMP plugin that has a checkbox "Use This Content as AMP Content" and a full editor for the actual AMP content. I could obviously install or uninstall plugins at any time, and I would hope WP-REST would handle it gracefully, or presumably, maybe I need to do a query before each post (in which case, how would that work)?

As far as I understand the REST-API, these fields are not 'meta' fields (I could be wrong).

Is there a way to set these (and other) fields using WP-REST API, or would I need to write my own plugin to expose those fields TO the WP-REST API. If that is the case (and it might very well be), how would I find a list of the available fields for a post?

Comment: Plugins will store most custom data as `post_meta` or `option` data. Sometimes the best avenue forward is to peek into the plugin code and see where you find calls to functions that update those. You can also get some visibility by using your browser inspector in the Admin and inspect the custom fields that the plugins are providing, field `name` property usually corresponds to option or post_meta keys. Use these clues to search the database.

Comment: Thanks Simran, I was hoping to automate it a little bit, so I wouldn't have to deconstruct a gazillion plugins. :)